Problem upgrading CiviCRM 5.76.4 to 5.79.0 (or 5.78.0)
I get this error after upgrading the CiviCRM web server code from 5.76.4 to 5.79.0, clearing the cache and then attepting to update the database by running .../wp/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/upgrade&reset=1
Fatal error: Declaration of Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ServiceLocator::get(string $id) must be compatible with Psr\Container\ContainerInterface::get($id) in /home/keebleco/public_html/app/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/ServiceLocator.php on line 41
Restoring the 5.76.4 web codebase resolved the error. I could then successfully upgrade from 5.76.4 to 5.77.1, but upgrading from 5.77.1 to 5.78.0 produced the same error.
Platform: WordPress 6.7.1, php 8.1 (or 8.2 or 8.3), Symphony 5.3.0 (from ...Symfony/config/CHANGELOG.md), psr 1.03 (from ...psr/http-client/CHANGELOG.md)
